# Ubuntu 14.04 can't detect the touchpad

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside to windows 8 and it can't detect the touchpad ?

Comment: What kind of touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

Please type

`xinput`

Detect if your touchpad has an ID (a number assigned to it). Post back the results, or type

```
xinput set-prop x "Device Enabled" 1
```

where x is the number assigned to the touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xinput from the terminal. This is how you do it:

1) Check the name of your device:

```
xinput list
```

2) See available options for your device:

```
xinput list-props "Your Device Name"
```

3) Edit settings (to make settings consistent after reboot/shutdown just add this command to Startup Applications):

```
xinput set-prop "Your Device Name" "Option Name" "Value"
```

Here is an example commandto activate locked drags:

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Locked Drags" 1
```

To activate Circle Scrolling just look for it in your device available options and play with them until you get the desired result, then add the command to Startup Applications and you're done!

(OR)

Use another nice GUI application you can try is touchpad-indicator:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```